# Scaled down image with css transform is cropped if overflow is hidden

Tags: html, overflow, css-transforms

I have an image (or more generally some content into a `<div>`) that is bigger than the viewport.

Since the user is not expected to see the part of the image not visible I have set the css property

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This prevents scrolling and scroll bars to appear.

Then at some point (user interaction) the image is scaled down with a CSS animation, for example:

```
transition: transform 0.5s;
transform: scale(0.5);
```

Unfortunately as the image shrinks the parts of it that were not initially visible still remain hidden as the image is resized **because of the `overflow: hidden` propery**

Is there a way to avoid this?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk58thv4/2/)

---

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img id="picture" src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/453915main_2010-3355_full.jpg"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display:  block;
    left:     10px;
    top:      10px;
    width:    500px;
    height:   500px;
}

#picture {
    position: absolute;
    width:    3000px;
    height:   2000px;
    left:    -1000px;
    top:     -500px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function()
{
    $('#container').on('click', resize);
}
);

function resize()
{
    $('#container').css(
    {
        'transition': 'transform 0.5s',
        'transform':  'scale(0.5)'
    } );
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @LGSon just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because the transformation is applied also to the `width` and `height` properties of the element transformed.

This issue can be solved by enclosing the scaled `<div>` into a ***wrapper*** `<div>` of the same size.

Then `overflow: hidden` is applied on the **wrapper** while the transformation still applies to the wrapped `<div>`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxu6yo9n/)